# transformation from map to laser

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a robot system which has frame odom and laser. tf publish the transfermation from odom to laser. I am building my own localization node which publish the frame "map" and the transformation from map to odom. When I use rviz, if I select odom as fixed frame, I can see the laser data. If I select "map" as fixed frame, rviz complains that there is no transformation from map to laser. I thought since I defined the transformation from map to odom, and the existing system has the transformation from odom to laser, rviz should be able to  figure out the transformation from map to laser. But this does not seem to be the case. What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309013/transformation-from-map-to-laser/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andy West](https://answers.ros.org/users/32333/andy-west/) on 2018-11-21**:
Try `rosrun tf view_frames` which will produce a graph showing the connections between the TF frames.  Use `evince frames.pdf` to view the graph.  Are all the frames joined up as you expect?

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-11-21**:
I can see map->odom->base_link->base_footprint. But laser it not there.

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-11-21**:
Please note that the transformation from odom to base_link is inside tf. However, the transformation from base_link to Laser is described in tf_static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the root cause was the time when running bag files. I need to set use_sim_time to be true. fine.

---

Originally posted by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) with karma: 102 on 2018-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0